# Error on install of ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, npm-install

[I received this error when I typed $ npm install ionic -g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVk2W.png)

Please how do i resolve this issue.

I'm not behind any proxy.

Comment: Maybe you could try to open terminal as "Administrator", and execute `npm install -g ionic`. Regards.

Comment: Hello, I've tried administrator and i'm still getting this same problem.